# « Synopsis » : est-il courant ? signification(s) ? genre(s) ?

Tags: usage, genre, dictionnaires, grec

J'ai quelques questions concernant le mot *synopsis*.

D'après Larousse :

> Bref exposé écrit d'un sujet de film, constituant l'ébauche d'un scénario.

L'emploi du mot désignant **une vue d'ensemble d'une science, d'une question** comme on le voit ici :

> [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/synopsis) :
>
> Ouvrage, tableau présentant une vue synoptique de l'ensemble ou de
>   l'une des parties d'une œuvre, d'une science, d'une question, ou qui
>   en donne un aperçu.

n'est-il pas courant ?

En outre selon Larousse le mot est **masculin** (mentionnant qu'il était auparavant féminin), tandis que TLFi dit qu'il faut faire la différence selon l'emploi : masculin (ou bien féminin) pour résume scénario et féminin pour aperçu scientifique.

Pourquoi existe-t-elle cette incohérence ? Quel genre faut-il utiliser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le Larousse est très clair sur l'emploi :

- [Au masculin](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/synopsis/76203) :  *Bref exposé écrit d'un sujet de film, constituant l'ébauche d'un  scénario.*
- [Au féminin](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/synopsis/76202?q=synopsis#75322) : *Bref aperçu sur l'ensemble d'une science, d'un objet d'enseignement.
  Tableau synoptique embrassant toutes les parties d'une science.*

La seule différence entre le TLFi et le Larousse est que le Larousse précise qu'autrefois le mot dans le sens de "résumé" était féminin alors que le TLFi dit que l'on peut encore le trouver dans un genre ou dans l'autre.

Il n'y a pas d'incohérence aujourd'hui. Pour le Larousse il s'agit de deux mots homographes dont le genre précisera le sens.

Comment: Je n'ai pas vu que Larousse donne tous les deux définitions. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

*Synopsis* est le plus souvent employé aujourd'hui pour désigner le résumé d'un film.

Les autres usages sont beaucoup moins fréquents. Le féminin se perd au point de risquer parfois d'être pris pour une faute.

[image]